# Error building pipeline in Foundry Code Repos, Code works in Preview mode but fails in Build mode

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

We keep getting the following error on a Foundry Code Repo transform. It works in preview mode, but fails in build mode.

```
No transforms discovered in the pipeline from the requested files. 
Please add the transform to the pipeline definer. 
If using the Build button in Authoring, please ensure you are running the build from the file where the transform is generated. 
Also note generated transforms may not be discovered using the Authoring Build button, and can be triggered
instead through the Dataset Preview app.: {filesWithoutDatasets=[transforms-python/src/name_of_transform_file.py]}
```

The input dataset is the result of a Data Connector REST ingest. And there's a column which I will call `jsonResponseColumn` that contains the actual json response from said ingest.
The code roughly looks like

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, ArrayType, StringType, DecimalType
from transforms.api import transform_df, Input, Output

@transform_df(
    Output("output_df_location"),
    input_df=Input("input_df_location"),
)
def compute(input_df):

    schema = create_schema()

    parsed_df = input_df
    parsed_df = parsed_df.withColumn('newField1', F.from_json(parsed_df.jsonResponseColumn, schema, {"mode": "FAILFAST"}))
    parsed_df = parsed_df.withColumn('newField2', F.explode(parsed_df.newField1.fieldInJsonResponse))
    parsed_df = parsed_df.withColumn('newField3', parsed_df.newField2.nestedFieldInJsonResponse)

    parsed_df = parsed_df.withColumn(
        'id', ...
    ).withColumn(
        'key', ...
    ).withColumn(
        .....
    )

    return parsed_df.select(
        ...
    )

def create_schema():
    //basically returns a StructType([...]) that matches the json response from the REST ingest
```

Comment: Can you share what's in your pipeline.py please? and your rough folder structure, that sounds like where the problem is´

Comment: Yep, you're right!

The sub-folder of this x-form file was missing in the pipeline.py. I added the missing x-form sub-folder and it worked. 
And just so other devs don't have to update this file every time they add a new sub-folder, I moved all the sub folders to /transforms and changed pipeline.py to what I have below & it works too!

`from transforms.api import Pipeline
import repo_name.transforms as transforms
my_pipeline = Pipeline()
my_pipeline.discover_transforms(transforms)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sub-folder of this x-form file was missing in the `pipeline.py`. I added the missing x-form sub-folder and it worked.
And just so other devs don't have to update this file every time they add a new sub-folder, I moved all the sub folders to `/transforms` and changed `pipeline.py` to what I have below & it works too!

```
from transforms.api import Pipeline 
import repo_name.transforms as transforms 
my_pipeline = Pipeline() 
my_pipeline.discover_transforms(transforms)
```